# Service Broadcaster/Runnable wont stop

Tags: android, service, android-service, broadcast, runnable

I have a Foregound Service with a broadcaster.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Service  
    Log.d("Service","Service started");

    startTime = intent.getLongExtra("STARTTIME", 0);
    endTime = intent.getLongExtra("ENDTIME", 0);
    isRunning = true;

    postNotification();

    // Broadcaster
    handler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable);
    handler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, DELAY);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

When I try to stop the service the `onDestroy()` runs and all is fine, but the `updateRunnable` keeps on going so the broadcasting still occurs.

```
private Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        Log.d("Service", "run");            
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if(endTime > 0 && (currentTime-startTime) >= endTime) {
            isRunning = false;

            // Alarm
            AlarmNotification alarmNotification = new AlarmNotification(context);
            alarmNotification.startAlarm();

            // Notification
            AppNotification notify = new AppNotification(context);
            notify.stopNotification();

            update();

            // Tried them all:
            stopService(intentBroadcaster);
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        } else {
            update();
        }
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 1 seconds
    }
};
```

As you can see I have tried every stop command I can think of. What am I doing wrong here? How do I stop the broadcasting / runnable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your broadcaster keeps running because your application process is still running, so your thread will keep on executing unless you told it not to.

It's easy to stop your thread, in your run method:

```
private boolean shouldContinue = true;
private Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
         // ... whaterver your doing
         if(shouldContinue){
             handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
         }
    }
};

public void onDestroy(){
    shouldContinue = false;
}
```